# Linux gives different result from Windows after import with osm2pgsql

Tags: postgis, django

I've done a blank Django project. Then shared it via git on `gitlab`.
Then downloaded a [very small region from geofabrik](http://download.geofabrik.de/europe/france/mayotte.html)
Then:

- in Windows I've imported it via:
  `osm2pgsql -c -U xx -d yy -H localhost -W -E`**`4326`**`~/myfile.osm.pbf`
- in Linux I had to change **`4326`** to **`3857`** to make it work, otherwise coordinates in the admin interface didn't show up properly.

From there I've made my models:

Here's are my models (all the same fields for `Line`, `Polygon`, `Point` and `Roads`, just one is enough):

```
class PlanetOsmLine(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'planet_osm_line'
        managed = False

    osm_id = models.BigIntegerField(primary_key=True)
    # ...tons of other field (unused)...
    way = GeometryField(default=None)
```

Now, for the same `osm_id`, this requests works under Windows, and gives me many results but under Linux I have an empty array (*!!*):

```
source = PlanetOsmPolygon.objects.get(osm_id="717295797").way
print([a.osm_id for a in PlanetOsmPolygon.objects.filter(
    way__contains=source
)])
```

What am I doing wrong, what are the tests I should do to make it work/look for the problem? I dont know where to start.

Answer (score 1):

Answer:

`osm2pgsql 0.88.1` doesn't import properly when setting option "`-E 4326`"

-> manual compiling latest version under Mint gave me: `osm2pgsql 0.96.0 (64 bit id space)`

And the import went fine and all queries now work. So be careful: the official package might not work, try to manual compile (very easy (if I could do it, anybody can do it **`;^)`**)).